# Force a "dist" diagonal to 1

Tags: r

Is is possible to force a distance object from the stats package to be something other than 0?

Here I try forcing it to something else and I can alter the upper or lower but not the diagonals:

```
set.seed(10)
x <- matrix(rnorm(25), ncol = 5)
y <- dist(x, diag =TRUE)
z <- 1 - as.matrix(y)
as.dist(z, diag =TRUE)
```

gives:

```
           1          2          3          4          5
1  0.0000000                                            
2 -0.9030066  0.0000000                                 
3 -0.9803571 -1.9319785  0.0000000                      
4 -1.5249747 -2.3673155 -1.5928891  0.0000000           
5 -2.7903980 -2.8020380 -2.2491893 -1.5839067  0.0000000
```

rather than the expected:

```
           1          2          3          4          5
1  1.0000000                                            
2 -0.9030066  1.0000000                                 
3 -0.9803571 -1.9319785  1.0000000                      
4 -1.5249747 -2.3673155 -1.5928891  1.0000000           
5 -2.7903980 -2.8020380 -2.2491893 -1.5839067  1.0000000
```

Maybe I have to output it as a matrix object instead because there's something about forcing the diagonals to be not 0 that causes it to not conform to the way "dist" objects are handled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not with `dist()`; it doesn't store the diagonal, just a flag to indicate if it should be printed via the `print()` method.

This is not unexpect; `dist()` is a compact way of storing distance matrices, not symmetric matrices in general. In a distance matrix, by definition, the distance between an observation and itself is 0. Hence `dist()` treats the diagonal as the trivial thing it is and doesn't store it.

If I wanted to do what you want to, I would use the guts of `dist()` and store the data as `dist()` does, in a function, say `mydist()` with class `"mydist"`, but then write `print.mydist()` taking code from the `print.dist()` method, but using another value for the diagonal, and write `as.matrix.mydist()` to do the conversion to a matrix. Your class could could either store the values for the diagonal (if they varied) or just a single value that you want the diagonal to be.

Essentially then, all you'd need to do is store the diagonal value(s) you want as an extra attribute, then provide `print()` and `as.matrix()` methods that drew from that attribute to print or populate the matrix.

Comment: Thanks Gavin.  Figured this to be the case.  Thanks for the alternative approach as well.

Answer (score 3):

A dist object is not a matrix, although there is a coercion function to make one,( which you already know.) If you wanted a matrix object like a dist object you could do this:

```
> z <- as.matrix(y)
> diag(z) <- 1
> z[upper.tri(z)] <- NA
> z
         1        2        3        4  5
1 1.000000       NA       NA       NA NA
2 2.515850 1.000000       NA       NA NA
3 2.093508 2.443131 1.000000       NA NA
4 2.734773 1.985341 2.652412 1.000000 NA
5 1.107235 2.012257 2.134162 1.913537  1
```